# convert array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Could you please help. I need to convert array to vector in this code. I just dont really understand how to execute it in the whole code. I know that it should be void "TreeSort(std::vector &array)", but how to work with the rest of the code? Thank you for your help.

```
template <typename T>

void TreeSort(T array[], size_t size)
{
    struct tree_t
    {
        tree_t *left, *right;
        T value;

        tree_t(T&& _value = T())
        {
            left = right = nullptr;
            value = forward <T>(_value);
        }



        T* operator()(T array[])
        {
            if (this->left)
                array = this->left->operator()(array);

            *array++ = move(this->value);
            if (this->right)
                array = this->right->operator()(array);
            return array;
        }
    } root(move(array[0]));

    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        bool inserted = false;
        tree_t* p_root = &root;
        while (!inserted)
        {
            if (array[i] < p_root->value)
            {
                if (p_root->left) p_root = p_root->left;
                else
                {
                    p_root->left = new tree_t(move(array[i]));
                    inserted = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (p_root->right) p_root = p_root->right;
                else
                {
                    p_root->right = new tree_t(move(array[i]));
                    inserted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    root(array);
}
```

Comment: "I know that it should be void "TreeSort(std::vector &array)", but how to work with the rest of the code? "  What specific problems arose?

Comment: @L.F. He probably just wants to replace T array[] with a std::vector<T>.